# How to pass a list by reference?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to implement a function 'add' that combines the list `L1` with `L2` into `L3`:

```
def add(L1,L2,L3):
    L3 = L1 + L2

L3 = []
add([1],[0],L3)
print L3
```

The code above produces an empty list as a result instead of `[1,0]` - This means that `L3` wasn't passed by reference.

How to pass `L3` by reference?

Comment: Don't; just return the combined lists. `L3 = add([1], [0])`.

Comment: Yes, python does **not** suppot pass-by-reference semantics

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lists are already passed by reference, in that *all* Python names are references, and list objects are mutable. Use slice assignment instead of normal assignment.

```
def add(L1, L2, L3):
    L3[:] = L1 + L2
```

However, this isn't a good way to write a function. You should simply return the combined list.

```
def add(L1, L2):
    return L1 + L2

L3 = add(L1, L2)
```

Comment: "Use slice assignment instead of normal assignment." So why does normal assignment not work?

Comment: Because `L1 + L2` creates a new list object which gets assigned to `L3`, rather than replacing the *elements* of the list that `L3` already refers to. In many cases it may not matter, but the OP is specifically asking about a scenario where they expect an existing list to be updated.

Comment: so L3 (the reference to the list L3) is being passed by value, not by reference, and that's why you can't directly change L3 -the reference- inside the function, instead having to do a "slice assignment" (so not having to change L3) ? :P How elegant is C++ in that regard.

Comment: The function has little to do with it. `L3 = ...` *never* has anything to do with whatever `L3` currently refers to.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with:

```
L3[:] = L1 + L2
```

#### Test Code:

```
def add(L1, L2, L3):
    L3[:] = L1 + L2

L3 = []
add([1], [0], L3)
print(L3)
```

#### Results:

```
[1, 0]
```

Comment: Something I can empathise with!

Answer (score 4):

If you want changes to be made inplace, you'd need to perform operations that modify the list *inplace*. This would mean any of the `list` instance methods. In this particular instance, you could look at `list.extend`.

```
def add(L1, L2, L3):
    L3.extend(L1 + L2)   # creates a new list object and copies it into L3
```

Since this creates a an copy (which may be inefficient), you can *instead* use two `extend` calls in its place -

```
def add(L1, L2, L3):
    L3.extend(L1)        
    L3.extend(L2)
```

Calling `L3.extend` modifies the original list in place. With your current code, `L1 + L2` creates a new list, and re-assigns `L3` to that object (and the original object that `L3` was referring to was not touched).

---

If you'd like to generalise this to any number of lists, I'd recommend taking a look at using variable arguments:

```
from itertools import chain

def add(L3, *L):
    L3.extend(chain.from_iterable(L))
```

Here's an example of how it works:

```
>>> L3 = []
>>> add(L3, [1], [2], [3])
>>> L3
[1, 2, 3]
```

As a matter of good practice, you should either

- define a function that does not modify the original structure, but returns a new value you can assign from the caller, OR
- define a function that modifies structures in place, and returns nothing.

Another user note: `L3[:] = ...` will *replace* `L3` of all its previous contents with the items from `L1 + L2`. On the other hand, `L3.extend(...)` will not destroy what was previously in `L3`, but is instead *extended* by what it is passed. I'd recommend evaluating your use case and using the more appropriate method to the situation.

However, to cater to that case, you can build on the accepted answer's method using inplace assignment with `__setitem__`:

```
def add(L3, *L):
    L3[:] = chain.from_iterable(L)
```

Which works the same way, and should be very efficient for many lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly pass a variable by reference in Python, but you can update properties on existing objects.

Therefore, what you can do is update values on `L3`, all of them in your case, so you could do it like this:

```
def add(L1 ,L2, L3):
    L3[:] = L1 + L2

L3 = []

add([1], [0], L3)

print L3
```